# Google Chrome starts but fails to open https websites: "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: firefox, chrome, libraries

These were Chrome's error messages on the command line:

> ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
>
> [11850:11915:0210/111421.109731:ERROR:bus.cc(394)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
>
> [11850:11875:0210/111421.366506:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(922)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for translate.googleapis.com failed err=-5992
>
> [11850:11878:0210/111421.366506:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(922)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for clientservices.googleapis.com failed err=-5992

...

This turned out to be the resolution in my case:

For some stupid reason, I had set my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to include `/usr/local/firefox`  where my most recent Firefox version resides. There, Chrome finds `libnss*` libraries which differ from those in `/usr/lib64`. Removing `/usr/local/firefox` from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, e.g.

```
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

so that it is just empty, solves the problem for Chrome. (Firefox is working with or without the fix.)

I thought I'ld post this here even after it's been resolved.

Comment: You you have a fix, please create an answer.

Comment: It is perfectly ok to [answer one's own questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), but you should do that in a proper answer, not in the question itself.

Comment: @John: Thanks for telling me how to handle this!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by Google Chrome using a version of `libnss3.so` in
`/usr/local/firefox` which came with Firefox 58.0.1.
`/usr/local/firefox/libnss3.so` differs from `/usr/lib64/libnss3.so` 
which seems to be the one that Google Chrome relies on. The problem arose after adding `/usr/local/firefox` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in order to get an installation of Firefox 58.0.1 in `/usr/local` running.  Removing `/usr/local/firefox` from
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has solved the problem with Google Chrome.

It was kind of treacherous that both browsers, Google Chrome (version 64.0.3282.140 (64-bit)) and Firefox 58.0.1 (installed in `/usr/local/firefox`), were nicely running side by side for a few days until a reboot made the change in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` effective for Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same problem while starting chrome as child process from java program directly under eclipse IDE.

Eclipse has curiously extended the environment with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/firefox`

Adding an additional environment setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/nonexisting_dir` to launch configuration solved the problem.